# R can't find function pure.error.anova

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to create an **ANOVA** table with pure errors and `lack-of-fit errors`, but **R** gives me the following message when I try to use the function `pure.error.anova`:

```
Error: could not find function pure.error.anova
```

Why isn't this function being found?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the function is now deprecated. Use `pureErrorAnova` instead.

```
library(alr3)
?pureErrorAnova # to see the help file.
```